# Regarding ARCGIS Curvature values

Tags: elevation, curvature

I originally had a DEM .tif raster in Decimal degrees. I projected it into a PCS with the spatial reference in ArcGIS as: WGS_1984_UTM_ZONE_44N

Then, I took the Curvature tool and with a Z-factor of 1 (i used value of 1 because i assumed units are in meters), I computed the profile,plan and general curvatures.

However, I obtained values for the values as such:

plan: high = 128, low = -175
profile: high = 185, low = -148
overall : high = 261, low = -360

I was expecting lower values and not sure how could i interpret the absolute numbers in this case.

Answer (score 1):

ok i see what is going on.

the output of arcgis is in 1/100 of a z unit. so I had to divide entire raster by 100 to obtain the correct values. thanks and sorry for creating a thread